# Finding the first numbered cell in a specified range, then applying ArrayFormula to that formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Sheets, I'm currently using this formula to find the first cell in a specified range that fulfills the ISNUMBER() condition:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(AC!D9:K9,ISNUMBER(AC!D9:K9)), 1)
```

This is working fine. However I need to apply this to an entire column, so one alternative would be dragging it down so subsequent cells contain a similar formula, for example the cell below this one would contain:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(AC!D10:K10,ISNUMBER(AC!D10:K10)), 1)
```

And this works too. But I'd like to find a way to make it cleaner and use ArrayFormula to apply it to the entire column, and the default `Ctrl + Shfit + Enter` formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(FILTER(AC!D9:K9,ISNUMBER(AC!D9:K9)), 1))
```

Isn't working. Anyone know how I could make it work?

Comment: What's the purpose of `INDEX`?

Comment: @I'-'I to find the first value if the filtered array

Answer (score 0):

`index` does not work with `ArrayFormula`

Please try:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(
TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR( 1 * D9:K12)),,2^99)),
"\d+"),"no number here"))`

[image]

---

## How it works

`IFERROR( 1 * D9:K12)`

will return numbers only from range `D9:K12`.

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR( 1 *D9:K12)),,2^99))`

gives an array of numbers delimited by space. If a row has no number, it will return spaces.

`REGEXEXTRACT( expression , "\d+")`

will find the first number from a string.

**Edit**

To convert numbers into number format :

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(
TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(1*D9:K12)),,2^99)),
"\d+") * 1,"no number here"))`

Comment: @CodeIntern, please see if my answer suits you.